# Why will my bot not send the message using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My bot's code works in the other chats but when I try to make it send it in the cafe chat, it wont send it and I get this in the log:

[image]

Here is the code that is not working:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.includes('☕cafe'));
  if (!channel) return;
  
  const welcome = {
    color: 0xF2CC0D,
    title: `**WELCOME TO THE SERVER, ${member.user.tag} !!**`,
    description: `I hope you will enjoy it here! \n A place full of chaos and wonder!`,
    thumbnail: {
      url: member.user.avatarURL(),
    },
    fields:[
    {
      name: 'welcome',
      value: 'Welcome again to Star City, !! Feel free to go grab some self roles in #self-roles and go choose a color in #mall !!!',
      inline: false
    },
    {
      name: 'commands!',
      value: 'Do: `!help` for all the bot commands!',
      inline: false
    }
   ],
   timestamp: new Date(),
  };

  channel.send({ embed: welcome });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you have a non-text-based channel with a name that includes `☕cafe`.

`member.guild.channels.cache.find()` will return a [guild channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel). It can be anything; a TextChannel, a VoiceChannel, a CategoryChannel, a NewsChannel, etc. Only [TextChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) and [NewsChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/NewsChannel) has a `send()` method. If your `channel` is something else, you'll receive a `TypeError: channel.send is not a function`.

Luckily, channels have an [`isText()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=isText) method that indicates whether the channel is text-based. You can use it in your `find()`'s callback:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (channel) => channel.name.includes('☕cafe') && channel.isText()
  );
  if (!channel) return;
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Channel
As you can see in the docs the channel class does not have a send method
Look for a text channel instead https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send